# c++ palindrome program using arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, string, visual-studio, palindrome

I'm having trouble with the first if statement, when the program enters the loop it skips over the if statement. My program is supposed to test if the input is a palindrome and then print it out, (the 'Reverse' array is just to print out the original phrase backwards if it passes through the test). If the palindrome is "madam I'm adam" the output should be "madamimadam" no capitalization or punctuation. I'm not sure if the arrays will take care of that or if I need another conditional test to take out those characters? If someone could please look over my code and tell me what's wrong/what I can do I'd greatly appreciate it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    //Variables and Arrays

    char Phrase[80];

    char Reverse[80];

    char* Palindrome = Reverse;

    int i, j, test = 1;

    cout << "Please enter a sentence to be reversed: ";
    cin >> Phrase;

    cin.getline(Phrase, 80);
    int length = strlen(Phrase);

    for(i = 0; i < (length/2); i++) // do a loop from 0 to half the length of the string
    {
        if(test == 1) // test for palindrome
        {
            if(Phrase[i] != Phrase[length-i-1]) // check if the characters match
            {
                test = 0; // if they don't set the indicator to false
            }
        }
        else
        {
            break; // if it is not a palindrome, exit the for loop
        }
    }

    if(test == 1) //test to print out the phrase if it's a palindrome
    {
        cout << "Phrase/Word is a Palindrome." << endl;

        for(j = strlen(Phrase) - 1; j >= 0; Palindrome++, j--)
        {
            *Palindrome = Phrase[j];
            cout << "The reverse is: " << Reverse << endl << endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Phrase/Word is not a Palindrome." << endl;
    }

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Equality** vs **Assignment**

`=` represents assignment so the statement `test = 1` will set `test` to 1. Due to the int to bool conversion, if `test` is non-zero, it will convert to `true`. So in your code, every `if(test...)` will evaluate to `true`

To solve this problem, you should test for equality using `==`.

And your logic is wrong in the first loop: `test` initialized to 0 and will never equal 1 so the first loop is useless. Try this

```
int test = 1;
```

Comment: Okay I fixed that for the two if(test == 1) statements. Now my output will correctly tell me if it's not a palindrome, but it won't say if it is when I type one correctly.

Comment: @T-Bird soo, its not a palindrome everytime?

Comment: No..The input will allow for any kind of string. The loop tests if it's a palindrome, while the second loop will reverse it if the first is true

Comment: Something else is wrong with the program aside from those few logical errors, I believe it's the first for loop

Answer (score 2):

You Using assignment insted of using equality

```
 if(test = 1) //Logical error. which will always be true
//it should be
if(test == 1)
```

Modified your code to work below

http://ideone.com/GnO6hB